# Finding the sum of special multiplications

Tags: combinatorics, computability

Let $n$ be an integer and $a_1, \dots, a_n$ positive reals.
$\forall 1 \leq i < j \leq n$ let $a_{i, j}$ be a positive number.
Let $k \leq n$ be a positive integer.
I would like to find an efficient way (either a closed formula, or an algorithm polynomial in $n$, $k$) to find

$ \sum_{S \subseteq \{1,\dots,n\}, |S| = k} \prod_{i \in S} a_i \prod_{i, j \in S, i < j} a_{i, j}$

EDIT:

I see that it is sufficient to find

$ \sum_{S \subseteq \{1,\dots,n\}, |S| = k} \prod_{i, j \in S, i < j} a_{i, j}$

We can multiply each $a_{i,j}$ by $\sqrt[k-1]{a_i a_j}$ and this way to get rid of $a_1,\dots,a_n$.

If you can't find a solution (possibly there is none), than any directions for how to get to this problem would be appreciated. Even an approximation algorithm is fine

Comment: Can you go by induction from k to k+1?

Comment: Not in an efficient way. For instance, I can find all the sums of sets of size $k + 1$ containing $i$ ($1 \leq i \leq n$)  by solving a problem for $k$: in this problem I get rid of $i$. For all $a_j$ for $j \neq i$ I multiply $a_j$ by $a_{i,j}$. Now I find the sums in this problem. I can do this for all $1 \leq i \leq n$, sum everything and divide by $k + 1$ to get a solution. But this means that I have to solve $n$ different problems for going from $k$ to $k + 1$ which leads to an exponential time.

Answer (score 0):

Define $$f(r,m)=\sum_{S\subseteq\{1,\ldots,n\},\atop|S|=r,\max S=m}\prod_{i,j\in S,\atop i<j}a_{i,j} $$
You want $$\sum_{m=k}^nf(k,m).$$
We have the recurrence
$$ f(r,m)= \sum_{r-1\le i<m}f(r-1,i)a_{i,m}$$

Thus to compute all $f(r,m)$, $1\le m\le n$, from the $f(r-1,m)$ takes $O(m^2)$ time, and to compute everything up to $r=k$ takes $O(km^2)$ time - and with suitable bookkeeping $O(n)$ space.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it has a problem: note that each multiplication in the desired sum is a multiplication of ${k \choose 2}$ elements (one element for each pair in S), while in your solution, there are only $k$ multiplications (when going from $r - 1$ to $r$ you add only one multiplication instead of $r - 1$ multiplications - we had to multiply by $a_{j,m}$ for each $j \in S$.